# How do I access a C# string on my aspx page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

I have declared a String on code-behind like so:

```
String myString = "Hi SO!";
```

How do I then print this on my aspx page?

`<%= myString %>` doesn't appear to be working.

**CS0103: The name 'myString' does not exist in the current context**

Comment: Could you show the complete C# code of the page? Especially where the string is declared.

Comment: Can you specify whether you are in fact using web forms or Asp.Net MVC? The question is ambiguous

Comment: Well is it declared at the class level ?

Comment: At the class level yes (outside of any sort of pageLoad method for example)

Comment: ASP.NET is not enaugh :). Is it ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: Web forms, my apologies.

Answer (score 5):

This may depend on where you have declared your string.

Make sure you are not declaring your string inside a method, the string should be a global variable inside the class

Also ensure the string is `protected` or `public`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your string is **protected** or **public** so the descendant class can see it.

Comment: I'm marking this answer as correct - purely for the fact it was the first to mention access modifiers which was, in fact, my problem. Silly me. Thanks a LOT for all other answers.

Answer (score 1):

The [access modifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) needs to be at least [`protected`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcd5672a%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

```
protected String myString = "Hi SO!";
```

The reason behind is that each `.aspx` page inherits from the code-behind class.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I've found to do this is create the string in my code behind page, then add a label on the aspx page.  On the code behind page, you will need to write some code like this:

```
string myString = "some value";
label1.Text = myString;
```

Make sure this is in the Page_Load event in the code behind page, depending on what you are trying to do.  In my case I wanted the string to be called at runtime when the page loads up.